# Merge 2 Numeric strings Alternatively every Nth place

Tags: c#, string, merge, numeric

I have 2 Numeric strings with commas:

8,1,6,3,16,9,14,11,24,17,22,19
and
2,7,4,5,10,15,12,13,18,23,20,21

and I need to merge them Alternatively every Nth place
(for Example every 4th place to get)

8,1,2,7,6,3,4,5,16,9,10,15,14,11,12,13,24,17,18,23,22,19,20,21

I've already examined all recommended solutions but nothing worked for me.

Here's my current progress:

```
string result = "";

// For every index in the strings
for (int i = 0; i < JoinedWithComma1.Length || i < JoinedWithComma2.Length; i=i+2)
{
    // First choose the ith character of the
    // first string if it exists
    if (i < JoinedWithComma1.Length)
        result += JoinedWithComma1[i];

    // Then choose the ith character of the
    // second string if it exists
    if (i < JoinedWithComma2.Length)
        result += JoinedWithComma2[i];
}
```

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: It's not every  4th character, it's every second embedded number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on the length of the strings or select the "ith character" because not all "elements" (read: numbers) have the same number of characters. You should split the strings so you can get the elements out of the result arrays instead:

```
string JoinedWithComma1 = "8,1,6,3,16,9,14,11,24,17,22,19";
string JoinedWithComma2 = "2,7,4,5,10,15,12,13,18,23,20,21";

var split1 = JoinedWithComma1.Split(',');
var split2 = JoinedWithComma2.Split(',');

if (split1.Length != split2.Length)
{
    // TODO: decide what you want to happen when the two strings
    //       have a different number of "elements".
    throw new Exception("Oops!");
}
```

Then, you can easily write a `for` loop to merge the two lists:

```
var merged = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < split1.Length; i += 2)
{
    if (i + 1 < split1.Length)
    {
        merged.AddRange(new[] { split1[i], split1[i + 1],
                                split2[i], split2[i + 1] });
    }
    else
    {
        merged.AddRange(new[] { split1[i], split2[i] });
    }
}

string result = string.Join(",", merged);
Console.WriteLine(
    result);      // 8,1,2,7,6,3,4,5,16,9,10,15,14,11,12,13,24,17,18,23,22,19,20,21
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/OYISP78961)**.

Comment: When the two strings have a different number of "elements", we could detect the largest of the two strings `int Max = Math.Max(SplitWithoutComma1.Length,SplitWithoutComma2.Length);` then use it in the for loop `for (int i = 0; i < Max; i += 2)`

Answer (score 1):

If you write a regular expression to get you a pair of numbers:

```
var r = new Regex(@"\d+,\d+");
```

You can break each string into a sequence of pairs:

```
var s1pairs = r.Matches(s1).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.ToString());
var s2pairs = r.Matches(s2).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.ToString());
```

And you can zip the sequences

```
var zipped = s1pairs.Zip(s2pairs,(a,b)=>a+","+b);
```

And join the bits together with commas

```
var result = string.Join(",", zipped);
```

---

How does it work?

The Regex matches any number of digits, followed by a comma, followed by any number of digits

In a string of

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

It matches 3 times:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

`Matches` returns a `MatchCollection` containing all these matches. To be compatible with LINQ `Select` you need to `Cast` the `MatchCollection` to an `IEnumerable<Match>`. It is this way because `MatchCollection` predates the invention of `IEnumerable<T>` so it's enumerator returns `object`s that need casting. Once turned into an `IEnumerable<Match>` each match can be `ToString`'d by a `Select`, producing a sequence of strings that are pairs of numbers separated by comma. An `s1pairs` is effectively a collection of pairs of numbers:

```
new []{ "1,2", "3,4", "5,6" }
```

Repeat the same for string 2

Zip the sequences. As you might imagine from the name, Zip takes one from A then one from B then one from A then one from B, merging them like a zipper on clothing so two sequences of

```
new [] { "1,2", "3,4" }

new [] { "A,B", "C,D" }
```

When zipped end up as

```
new [] { "1,2,A,B", "3,4,C,D" }
```

And all that remains is to join it back together with a comma

```
"1,2,A,B,3,4,C,D"
```